# MySQL Not Found and Other Problems

Tags: mysql

I'm on Lubuntu. I've installed lamp. PHP works, so does myphpadmin. However, when I try to run MySQL, there is a 'not found' error. How do I solve this?

Also, I mistakenly symbolically linked mysql to /www/html and need to break that link so I can start fresh. Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: first of all give us the output for `dpkg -l mysql-server` and update your answer. for symbolic link you can just delete it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the link wherever you created it

Have you installed mysql-client at all? Maybe try to reinstall it?